# Draw cube with 6 different colours for the 6 faces using METAL

Tags: objective-c, metal, metalkit

I want to draw a cube with 6 different colours. How can I do that? I am more interested in the logic behind, not the code. I want to have a colour buffer with the 6 colours, and a colour index buffer. I already drew the cube using a vertex buffer and a vertex index buffer. (objective-c is the language).

Thank you

Comment: Did you find this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/146418/metal-tutorial-swift-3-part-3-adding-texture ?

Comment: You'll probably want to duplicate the vertices such that each face has four distinct vertices. Then, you can either store the color index explicitly in each vertex as an attribute, or you can compute the face (color) index based on the `vertex_id` (something like `colorIndex = vertexID % 4`).